# Виртуальное наследование

Tags: c++

Почему данный код не работает?

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void print() const { 
        std::cout << "class A" << std::endl; 
    }
};

class B : public virtual  A {
public:
    void print() const { 
        std::cout << "class B" << std::endl; 
    }
};

class C : public virtual A {
public:
    void print() const { 
        std::cout << "class C" << std::endl; 
    }
};

class D : public B, public C {
public:
    using C::print;
};
```

Comment: Потому что нет функции main

Answer (score 2):

Виртуальное наследование введено, чтобы функция, которая наследуется через B и через C, определялась однозначно. Но при этом метод нельзя определить виртуальным. Ведь тогда в классах B и С он определен по-разному, как компилятору определять, какой вариант брать? Страуструп об этом пишет очень подробно. На практике редко используют виртуальное наследование из-за таких проблем.

Comment: В таблице виртуальных функций должны были бы появиться 2 функции с одинаковым именем и сигнатурой.